# Как повторить на nodejs функции из php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

По документации мне нужно сгенерировать соли, используя php, вот такой функцией:

```
bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

Проблема в том, что у меня на бекенде nodejs.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, аналог обеих функций на javascript

Comment: нет ни малейшего смысла искать аналог. Просто искать генератор соли на жс

Comment: Может тогда подскажите генератор соли на жс, который сгенерирует соли аналогичные по типу с тем, что генерирует функция в вопросе?

Comment: не нужно никаких "аналогичных по типу". Соль может быть любая. Поэтом у генератор соли тоже любой

Comment: `require('crypto').pseudoRandomBytes(16).toString('hex');`

Comment: @Yaant только `randomBytes(16)`

Comment: @AlexeyTen ха, забавно. Писал комментарий, не глядя в документацию, проверял в консоли, работало. :) Похоже, это недокументированный синоним — `crypto.randomBytes === crypto.pseudoRandomBytes` -> `true`.